# Why couldn't I access some blocked website?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, blocked-services

I tried to access some website which are blocked in my country using Tor Browser Bundle but they are still blocked. The sign of government showed that this website is blocked because of Junta's order. How do I access to this website? And what happened?

For example: soccersuck.com

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to connect to the web site in your example. It appeared that I was redirected to another web site (www.tcsd.info). Although I could not read the language in this site, it appeared to me that it shows Royal Thai police logo among other logos. My best estimate is that security forces have physically taken over the web site and censored it.

Comment: _"We appologize for the inconveniences.  Access to the requested information has been blocked by central police authority, international department for technologies and communications."_

Answer (score 0):

The websites maybe blocking the Tor users, you may want to try to visit the sites by online web proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same redirect that Roya reported. From https://who.is/ I get that the IP address is 202.57.128.231, and that the namerservers are ns1.guideball.com and ns2.guideball.com. Browsing 202.57.128.231 shows me the default nginx page ("Welcome to nginx on Fedora!"). But I can hit http://www.guideball.com, and maybe there's useful information there (in Thai).